# How to loop two arguments in one foreach loop after 1st arg finishes?

Tags: powershell, foreach

Suppose i have two different kind of servers

```
Function Query($Query) {
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
$a=$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close() 
$DataSet.Tables[0] }

$servers_typeA = Query "SELECT DISTINCT [server_typeA] FROM table" | Select -ExpandProperty server_typeA;
$servers_typeB = Query "SELECT DISTINCT [server_typeB] FROM table" | Select -ExpandProperty server_typeB;
```

I have a forloop that for now loops through servers in typeA and displays connections of databases for each of the servers in `$servers_typeA`

```
foreach($server in $servers_typeA)
```

instead of duplicating the same loop for typeB, so

```
foreach($server in $servers_typeB)
```

Is theer a way i can tell the forloop to loop typeB after A?

Essentially, like this?

```
foreach($server in $servers_typeA then $servers_typeB)
```

Comment: `foreach($server in @($servers_typeA, $servers_typeB))` ... array of arrays. When will you start to learn the basics of Powershell?

Comment: Not that I know of. What time or typing would it save? You COULD nest them; but that really wouldn't save any time, either.

Comment: @Olaf lol i already know the basics....i have been scripting for over a year in powershell, our entire department's automation is handled by me. all i am asking for is if there is a way. thats all. the array of arrays wont work for my case because the arguments are not an array. they are instead holding results from a query statement which gets stored with expand property.

Comment: So, then show us what IS in these variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply *concatenate* the arrays with `+` in order to loop over their combined items; a simplified example:

```
$servers_typeA = 'foo', 'bar'
$servers_typeB = 'baz', 'bam'

foreach ($server in $servers_typeA + $servers_typeB) {
  "processing server $server..."
}
```

**Note**: If there's a chance that the LHS of the concatenation is actually a scalar, not an array, use `@(...)` around it (not necessary for the RHS): `@($servers_typeA) + $servers_typeB`

The above yields:

```
processing server foo...
processing server bar...
processing server baz...
processing server bam...
```